# Changing webpage by math.random using cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am looking for a way to change webpage through a list without getting the same page twice. I have tried shuffling a list however when a new page is loaded it just reloads the script. So I guess I need to use some sort of cookie. However I am quite new to javascript. Can anyone please help me?

I was thinking something like this, just with a cookie of some sort:

```
var pages = ['sang1.html','sang2.html','sang3.html','sang4.html','sang5.html','sang6.html','sang7.html','sang8.html','sang9.html','sang10.html','sang11.html','sang12.html','sang13.html','sang14.html','sang15.html','sang17.html','sang18.html','sang19.html','sang20.html','sang21.html''sang22.html','sang23.html','sang24.html','sang25.html','sang26.html','sang27.html','sang28.html','sang29.html','sang30.html','sang31.html','sang32.html''sang33.html','sang34.html','sang35.html'];
var page = Math.floor((Math.random() * pages.length) + 1);
window.location.href = pages[page];
pages.splice(page);
```

Comment: I think using cookies is a good idea. Read here on how to set or retrieve them http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Take a look at the LocalStorage API.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var page = pages[Math.floor(Math.random() * pages.length)]
 window.location.href = pages[page]
```

Comment: but this does not remove any of the other pages. it just links to one directly

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic solution using **localstorage** as cookies would not be a good idea due to round trip

```
var pages = ['sang1.html', 'sang2.html', 'sang3.html', 'sang4.html', 'sang5.html', 'sang6.html', 'sang7.html', 'sang8.html', 'sang9.html', 'sang10.html', 'sang11.html', 'sang12.html', 'sang13.html', 'sang14.html', 'sang15.html', 'sang17.html', 'sang18.html', 'sang19.html', 'sang20.html', 'sang21.html'];
var page, visitedPages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("visitedPages"));
if (visitedPages === null) {
    visitedPages = [];
}
var unVisitedPages = difference(visitedPages, pages);
if(unVisitedPages.length === 0){//All pages visited at once
    //add your logic when all page visited
}
else{
    page = unVisitedPages[Math.floor(Math.random() * unVisitedPages.length)];
    localStorage.setItem("visitedPages", JSON.stringify(visitedPages.push(page)));
    window.location.href = page; //append if you want to kill cache"?ck="+new Date().getTime()
} 

function difference(a,b){//b -a
    var c = [];
    for(var i=0; i< b.length; i++){
        if(a.indexOf(b[i]) === -1){
            c.push(b[i]);
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: it seems like there is a problem with the script. Because when it is added it always loads sang1 and then goes to sang2 however it will not go from there. I cant realy se hw to fix this issue. Any help?

Comment: Hey, can you try with latest solution which is more straight and optimized.